# Clearing badges count on RN app using firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification

I have no worries sending push notifications to my RN app from my backend and adjusting badges count there, no matter there are 100 badges or 0. What I am curious about is how to clear that badge count without actually showing any new push notification? Is there any kind of "silent" push notifications that will never be showed but the badge count will be updated? I have this situation since I have web and mobile apps and if the user reads his notifications on WEB I want to reset its count on mobile as well without waiting to open the mobile app.

On my backend I'm using [firebase-admin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin) library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible to send a silent push without any sound and appear in notifications with this payload and it will set your badge no. reset means zero and 0 badge will not show

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You received simple notification!",
        "badge" : 0,
        "content-available" : 1
    }
}
```

OR

try options

```
const options = { content_available: true }
```

and pass options as an additional parameter

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload, options);
```

Comment: it seems right, but is it possible to do using `sendToDevice` method? I can't find this kind of type in their documentation

Comment: 'Messaging payload contains an invalid "aps" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification".

Comment: try options 
const options = {
    content_available: true
  }

Comment: admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload, options);

Comment: im still trying to make it, ill mark as correct answer if it works :)

Comment: yes, so I'm not sure about the `content_available` option yet, but I did managed to get rid of my badges on IOS by sending multicast message with such a payload: `const message = {
    notification: {},
    data: { key: '' },
    tokens: deviceTokens.map((v) => v.deviceToken),
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: {
          badge: 0,
          'content-available': 1,
        },
      },
    },
  };`